# Can I bounce the ball off defender to resume my dribble?

Tags: rules, basketball

Let's say I pick up my dribble accidentally. Can I bounce the ball off the defenders leg and resume my dribble or is that an illegal move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't bouncing it off the opposition, you are making a pass.   As long as your pass doesn't infringe on sportsmanship it is perfectly legal.   You would be possibly called for a tech if you throw it at an opponents face or overly hard at the upper part of their body.   This is a judgment call by the referee.   I have never seen someone called for a foul when they throw it off an opponents legs or lower body or bouncing it off their back.

Comment: I see. Appreciate the response.